# UTM for Windows 11 -- cannot change trackpad scroll direction

Tags: mouse, touchpad, scrolling

I am using an Apple trackpad with my main machine. I now have installed UTM and created a Windows 11 virtual machine. I would like to change the scroll direction. This should be fairly easy on a normal Windows platform. Unfortunately the VM does not recognize the trackpad. It apparently thinks it is a mouse.

I have changed the registry entry to change the scroll direction as follows, for the mouse that it thinks is connected but is not. It does not work.

The registry key is the following:

changed from 0 to 1 for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID\VID_0627&PID_001[ID}Device Parameters\FlipFlopWheel

Comment: I don’t think you’ll get much success here as most people aren’t savvy with Windows to the point of understanding how to modify the Windows registry.  Perhaps [SU] might be a better fit?  I’ll flag so a mod can migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem too and unfortunately configuring the Registry won't work here.

I'm running UTM version 4.2.5 and the current solution is to open the UTM global settings
[image]

navigate to the "Input" tab, and check the box
[image]

that reads "Invert Scrolling".

I've provided links to screenshots of where these settings are.

Hope this helps!